Counting Instances of an element with selenium and python
so I am working on a online class that requires me to use selenium to navigate to * Navigate to The Internet website (https://the-internet.herokuapp.com) - then to a specific child page (add/remove elements)then add some elements and count them and remove some and count the result. my first approach was rather ramshackle. I was able to get it to "work" (i.e correctly navigate and click elements) but unable to fill all the requirements (i.e I could not keep an a variable count and I didn't know how to add assertions)
So I settled on this approach
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec


class Webpage:
    element_count = 0

    def __init__(self, element_count, driver):
        self.element_count = element_count
        self.driver = driver

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com')

# Parent page loads
        wait.until(ec.url_to_be('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/'))

# Variables go here (as they depend on parent loading)

        add_remove_parent = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.LINK_TEXT, 'Add/Remove Elements')))

        driver.fullscreen_window()

    # This is where the functions happen
        add_remove_parent.click()
        #  * Assert that no elements have yet been added

        wait.until(ec.url_to_be('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/add_remove_elements/'))
        # Child Page Loaded

        wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Add Element"]')))

        def add_element(self):
            add_element_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Add Element"]')
            add_element_button.click()
            self.element_count += 1
            print(f'The element count is {self.element_count}')

        def delete_element(self):

            delete_element_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'added-manually')
            delete_element_button.click()
            self.element_count -= 1
            print(f'the element count is {self.element_count}')

    webpage=Webpage(self,element_count=0 ,driver)

    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

#

But , (and here is where I am getting it wrong) I don't seem to be (Instantiating?) if that is the right word -> the class correctly and would like some direction with this.As well as maybe some direction on correctly calling the methods on it. I've done it with simpler things , and i've done it with alot of the code abstracted away. But never on my own from scratch and I can't yet see what I'm missing.
Also, I know I don't have any assertions yet , I'll try to add those in after , maybe into the methods themselves or maybe separate.
Most times when I've tried the class does not seem to understand what the argument for self , or driver should be but I thought I provided that by saying it should be firefox.
Much appreciated for any help!

There are a number of issues with the class as defined.

The instantiation of the Webpage class should be Webpage(0, driver) instead of Webpage(self, element_count=0, driver).
The add_element and delete_element methods should be defined outside the try block.
The try block should encapsulate only the operations that might raise exceptions, not the whole script.

In the code that follows I will implement a script without using classes. It will make it easier to understand the process and will be fully commented. Afterwards I will implement a solution using classes.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Define the initial URL
INITIAL_URL = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com"

# Define the string constants to be used navigating the DOM
ADD_ELEMENT_XPATH = "//button[text()='Add Element']"
DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH = "//button[text()='Delete']"
CLASS_NAME_ADDED = "added-manually"

# Create a WebDriver instance and navigate to the initial URL
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(INITIAL_URL)

# Wait for the "Add/Remove Elements" link to be present
try:
    add_remove_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Add/Remove Elements"))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
    driver.quit()
    exit(0)

# Print a message when the initial page is loaded
print(f"Initial page loaded. {INITIAL_URL}")

# Click on the "Add/Remove Elements" link
add_remove_link.click()

try:
    add_element_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ADD_ELEMENT_XPATH))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
    driver.quit()
    exit(0)

# Print a message when the child page is loaded
print(f"Child page loaded. {driver.current_url}")

# Ensure a 'Delete' button is not already present
assert WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH))
)

# Initialize variables for tracking elements added and removed
elements_added = 0
elements_removed = 0

# Count the initial number of 'Delete' buttons
initial_count = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH))
assert initial_count == elements_added, "Initial 'Delete' button element count is not zero."

# Add 3 elements
for _ in range(3):
    add_element_btn.click()
    elements_added += 1

# Wait for the 'Delete' button to be clickable
delete_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH))
)

# If the 'Delete' button is displayed, count the elements and print information
if delete_btn.is_displayed():
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH)
    by_class = len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, CLASS_NAME_ADDED))
    added_count = len(elements)
    print(f"Added {added_count} 'Delete' buttons.")
    print(f"Found by class name: {by_class}")

# Assert that the added count matches the expected count
assert added_count == elements_added, "'Delete' button element count mismatch."

# If elements are present, delete one and update the count
if added_count > 0:
    delete_element_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH)
    delete_element_btn.click()
    elements_removed += 1
    print(f"Removed {elements_removed} 'Delete' button.")

# Calculate the expected number of elements present after deletion
expected_elements_present = elements_added - elements_removed

# Count the actual number of elements present
elements_present = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH))

# Assert that the actual number of elements matches the expected number
assert elements_present == expected_elements_present, "'Delete' button element count mismatch."

# Print the number of elements present
print(f"'Delete' button elements present: {elements_present}")

# If elements are present, delete all of them and update the count
if elements_present > 0:
    delete_clicks = 0
    delete_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, CLASS_NAME_ADDED)
    for delete_btn in delete_buttons:
        delete_btn.click()
        delete_clicks += 1
        print("Removed a 'Delete' button.")
    assert delete_clicks == elements_present, "'Delete' button clicks mismatch."

# Count the number of 'Delete' buttons remaining and assert that it is zero
button_count = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, DELETE_BUTTON_XPATH))
try:
    assert button_count == 0, f"{button_count} 'Delete' button elements remain."
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("No 'Delete' button elements remain.")

# Close the browser session
driver.quit()

Output:
Initial page loaded. https://the-internet.herokuapp.com
Child page loaded. https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/add_remove_elements/
Added 3 'Delete' buttons.
Found by class name: 3
Removed 1 'Delete' button.
'Delete' button elements present: 2
Removed a 'Delete' button.
Removed a 'Delete' button.
No 'Delete' button elements remain.

Here is the solution implemented using two classes, ElementHandler and WebpageMain. The ElementHandler class abstracts away the interaction with the Selenium webdriver and the WebpageMain class implements a run() method that does the driving.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class ElementHandler:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def wait_for_element(self, locator):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(locator)
            return element
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Loading took too much time!")
            self.driver.quit()
            exit(0)

    def count_elements_by_class_name(self, class_name):
        elements = self.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
        return len(elements)

    def count_elements_with_xpath(self, xpath):
        elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
        return len(elements)

    def click_element(self, element):
        element.click()

    def clickable_link_text(self, text):
        return self.wait_for_element(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, text))
        )

    def clickable_xpath_element(self, xpath):
        return self.wait_for_element(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
        )

    def find_elements_by_class_name(self, class_name):
        elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
        return elements

    def is_element_displayed(self, element):
        return element.is_displayed()

    def quit_driver(self):
        self.driver.quit()


class WebpageMain:
    def __init__(self, url, elements):
        self.element_handler = ElementHandler(url)
        self.add_element_xpath = "//button[text()='Add Element']"
        self.delete_button_xpath = "//button[text()='Delete']"
        self.class_name_added = "added-manually"
        self.elements_to_add = elements
        self.elements_added = 0
        self.elements_removed = 0
        self.add_element_btn = None

    def click_add_remove_link(self):
        add_remove_link = self.element_handler.clickable_link_text("Add/Remove Elements")
        print(f"Initial page loaded. {self.element_handler.driver.current_url}")
        add_remove_link.click()

    def find_add_element_button(self):
        return self.element_handler.clickable_xpath_element(self.add_element_xpath)

    def count_delete_buttons(self):
        return self.element_handler.count_elements_with_xpath(self.delete_button_xpath)

    def find_delete_button(self):
        return self.element_handler.clickable_xpath_element(self.delete_button_xpath)

    def click_add_element_button(self):
        self.element_handler.click_element(self.add_element_btn)
        self.elements_added += 1

    def is_delete_button_displayed(self):
        delete_btn = self.find_delete_button()
        return self.element_handler.is_element_displayed(delete_btn)

    def count_elements_added(self):
        return self.element_handler.count_elements_by_class_name(self.class_name_added)

    def click_delete_button(self, btn=None):
        if btn is not None:
            delete_element_btn = btn
        else:
            delete_element_btn = self.element_handler.clickable_xpath_element(self.delete_button_xpath)
        self.element_handler.click_element(delete_element_btn)
        self.elements_removed += 1
        print(f"Removed a 'Delete' button.")

    def find_added_buttons(self):
        return self.element_handler.find_elements_by_class_name(self.class_name_added)

    def run(self):
        self.element_handler.navigate_to_url()
        self.click_add_remove_link()
        self.add_element_btn = self.find_add_element_button()

        print(f"Child page loaded. {self.element_handler.driver.current_url}")

        assert self.count_delete_buttons() == 0, "Initial 'Delete' button element count is not zero."

        elements = 0

        for _ in range(self.elements_to_add):
            self.click_add_element_button()

        if self.is_delete_button_displayed():
            elements = self.count_elements_added()
            print(f"Added elements found by class name: {elements}")

        assert elements == self.elements_to_add, "Incorrect number of elements added."
        assert elements == self.elements_added, "'Delete' button element count mismatch."

        if elements > 0:
            self.click_delete_button()

        expected_elements_present = self.elements_added - self.elements_removed
        elements_present = self.count_delete_buttons()

        assert elements_present == expected_elements_present, "'Delete' button element count mismatch."

        print(f"'Delete' button elements present: {elements_present}")

        if elements_present > 0:
            delete_clicks = 0
            delete_buttons = self.find_added_buttons()
            for delete_btn in delete_buttons:
                self.click_delete_button(delete_btn)
                delete_clicks += 1
            assert delete_clicks == elements_present, "'Delete' button clicks mismatch."

        button_count = self.count_delete_buttons()
        try:
            assert button_count == 0, f"{button_count} 'Delete' button elements remain."
        except AssertionError as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            print("No 'Delete' button elements remain.")

        self.element_handler.quit_driver()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    INITIAL_URL = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com"
    webpage_main = WebpageMain(INITIAL_URL, 3)
    webpage_main.run()

Output:
Initial page loaded. https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/
Child page loaded. https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/add_remove_elements/
Added elements found by class name: 3
Removed a 'Delete' button.
'Delete' button elements present: 2
Removed a 'Delete' button.
Removed a 'Delete' button.
No 'Delete' button elements remain.


Thank you ! that's a great implementation and has given me ideas on how I might execute further challenges.
